# Using existing S3 bucket with source code to deploy with AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm new to AWS CDK and what I need is to deploy around 10 function that are currently stored as zip file inside a S3 Bucket

Here's the portion of the code I use

```
  public class CdkWorkshopStack : Stack
    {
        public CdkWorkshopStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
        {
            var deployBucket = new Bucket(this, "deploy-stack1");
            var bucketKey = "xxx-3496f166-0f1d-40b4-8766-c5d29e4950ff.zip";
            var xxx= new Function(this, "CdkWorkshopLambda", new FunctionProps
            {
                Runtime = Runtime.DOTNET_6,
                Code = Code.FromBucket(bucket: deployBucket, key: bucketKey),
                Handler = "app.handler",
                Environment = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["DELETE_S3_FILE_AFTER_PROCESSING"] = "true",
                    ["TMP_DOWNLOAD_BUCKET"] = "content-temporary-files"
                },
                FunctionName = "xxx",
                Architecture = Architecture.X86_64,
                Description = "Calculates the xxx for a given filename"
            });
```

Now my problem is the following, I need to read from a bucket that's now present in the enviorment I'm creating (since the bucket can be considered as a repo)

how can I specify a bucket that's external to the account/region?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`Bucket.fromBucketArn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.Bucket.html#static-fromwbrbucketwbrarnscope-id-bucketarn) and providing the ARN.

You'll have to make sure you have the required rights to access this bucket cross-account.